# Analyze intervals for gaps

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with roads that contain mileage of start/end of every road.

I need to analyze this data and get query with same data more rows that contain mileage of start/end of gaps between roads with filled column *name* with value '*gap*'.

Initial table:

```
id    name     kmstart   kmend
1     road1      0        150
2     road2     150       200
3     road3     220       257
4     road4     260       290
```

Result query:

```
id    name     kmstart   kmend
1     road1      0        150
2     road2     150       200
null  gap       200       220
3     road3     220       257
null  gap       257       260
4     road4     260       290
```

Comment: fyi: "name" is a reserved word and hence a really really bad choice for a column name. try: "road_name" ...

Comment: Real table is with different names. It is just an example

Comment: You should give us a "working example" .. not a fictional one that we then have to debug .. ;)

Comment: it was my mistake, i consider this for future. But now i can't change it. Because question has answers with this structure.

Comment: Is it certain that the first id starts at km 0 and not, for example, at km 4? If that is not guaranteed, that may need to be addressed as well. (And, similarly, is it possible you may need a "NULL" id for something at the end - in your example, if the final km was in fact 295?)

Comment: 'is it possible you may need a "NULL" id for something at the end' - no
//// startkm can be [0,999999]; endkm can be (startkm,999999]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT NULL, 'gap', previous_kmend AS kmstart, kmstart AS kmend
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, kmstart, kmend, LAG(kmend) OVER (ORDER BY kmstart, kmend) AS previous_kmend
  FROM roads
)
WHERE previous_kmend < kmstart
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, kmstart, kmend
FROM roads
ORDER BY kmstart, kmend
```

I just put up a quick test and it works for me.

It uses the LAG function to get the previous kmend row, and then returns the "gap" row if it is less than the current record's kmstart row. I've written an [article about the LAG function](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-lag/) recently so it was helpful to remember.

Is this what you're after?

Also, as the other commenters have mentioned, "name" isn't a good column name as it's a reserved word. I've left it here in the code so it's consistent with your question though.